# Controlling and svg image?

Tags: svg

I've made a very big SVG image and I would like to have it on a webpage in a set size iframe (or equivalent) with a control panel for scrolling/zooming.
Is this at all possible?
What should I be using? PHP? Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible, and I assume you will probably want to mainly use javascript.

There is a javascript library SVGpan which may be able to help. [SVGPan](https://code.google.com/p/svgpan/) and a demo here... [SVGPan demo](http://www.cyberz.org/projects/SVGPan/tiger.svg) that you can drag/pan/zoom.

Comment: Ah thanks. I had envisioned a control panel but that works even better.
How does one incorporate it into a website whilst still maintaining the capability however?